# jquery mobile trigger('create') callback function

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and using the $().trigger('create') function to initiate it. I need a callback after this function is done modifying the html with the new styling. Is this possible?

I need this because i need the new dimensions of the screen after an ajax load of new content.

Answer (score 0):

I would use TriggerHandler(). You can bind to your custom event...

See the DEMO at the bottom of the link:

http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Answer (score 0):

I found that the "updatelayout" event gets fired when I do a x$.trigger("create"). This from some js using Backbone...

```
var content$ = this.$el.find("#somediv");
content$.on('updatelayout', function () { alert("woo hoo"); });
content$.trigger("create"); // add some JQM magic, wait for the 'woo hoo'
```

From the jQuery api:

"This event is triggered by components within the framework that dynamically show/hide content, and is meant as a generic mechanism to notify other components that they may need to update their size or position."

It turns out that there is a devil in the detail. Not all triggered JQM content leads to a JQ "updatelayout" event. I had to add a wrapper div with 'data-role="controlgroup" in another case to get it to fire. More digging required...